# increasing the size of taping on a touch screen

Tags: android, android-studio

how to increase the size of taping on a touch screen? I mean how to let the app figures out the size of finger. 
using motion events in coding let's us use the standard tapping size, which I think 10 mm.

Comment: add padding to your control.

Comment: I am not using buttons on the UI. I am only trying to use gestures to perform some tasks on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that seperately. If you want to increase the touch area of `Button`, `TextView` and other UI elements, you can surround the elements with a say a `LinearLayout` that has the padding round the element and assign click to that layout too.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you put it seperately?

Comment: I need to let a tap on a touch screen be as big as a user fingertip size.

Comment: I do not have any buttons or edit text on a touch screen. I want the app to learn the size of users' fingertips

Comment: for example, if I have small index fingertip, the app will identify that my fingertip is for example 12mm and vice versa.